# Tension force of infinite series of masses?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics

A body of mass 1kg is connected to an infinite number of masses by means of an infinite number of ropes, as shown in the sketch below. A measurement shows that the tension force in 1st rope: 1N. Second rope: 2N. Third rope 4N, etc.

**Find m5**, assuming there is no friction.

[image]

My approach is:$$
m_{1} g-F_{s_{1}}=m_{1} a
$$
$$
a=\frac{m_{1} g-F_{s_{1}}}{m_{1}}
$$
$$
a=9 \frac{m}{s^{2}}
$$

But then this contradicts because:
$$
-S_{2}+S_{1}=-2 N+1 N=-1 N=m_{4} a
$$
$$
\Rightarrow m_{4}=\frac{-1}{9}<0 (!)
$$ 
 I think that this suggests that there are two accelerations going in two different directions and the rope at S1 will break...? But I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: yeah, but I have wracked all my brain but still come up with nothing good... im sorry if you find that bothersome

Comment: How do you get from $a=\frac{m_{1} g-F_{s_{1}}}{m_{1}}$ to $a=9 \frac{m}{s^{2}}$?

Comment: I have forgotten to type that m1 = 1kg. Edited.

Comment: If $m_1$ is 1kg, the whole assembly is accelerating the left at 1ms$^{-2}$. Now  you can figure out all the masses!

Comment: Can you tell me how you arrive at the result a = 1ms^-2?

Comment: Is it possible that "tension in first rope" means in the first rope from the left, between m4 and m5? Without the original in front of us, it's impossible to say. another possibility is that everything is moving left, not right, under the influence of an unknown external force. Your calculations seem to make sense. It's not possible to have m1 going down while tension increases towards the left.

Comment: All I can say is that the question is wrong. The tensions in the strings are bound to decrease as you go further away from the pulley (assuming there are no external forces except gravity).